# Upload is null after adding jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js reference

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

If I don't refer `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` I can get attachment on Post. If I refer it It's giving me null.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ContactSubmission", new AjaxOptions{ InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "updateSuccess" },
     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
      {
               ///code here
```

}

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(Contact contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if (contact != null)
       {
         string attachment = string.Empty;
         // HttpPostedFileBase Attachment
         if (contact.Attachment != null) attachment = SaveFile(contact.Attachment); 
                ......
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Have you accidentally referenced it twice"? Check your layout and/or bundle config

Comment: Nope. It only one place it is referenced on the page

Answer (score 7):

I modify the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` to work uploading files. 
First modification:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ext=true]", function (evt) {
        var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [],
            clickTarget = $(this).data(data_target),
            isCancel = clickTarget && clickTarget.hasClass("cancel");
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (!isCancel && !validate(this)) {
            return;
        }
        var formData;
        if (this.enctype && this.enctype === "multipart/form-data") {
            formData = new FormData(this);
        } else {
            formData = clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray());
        }

        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method || "GET",
            data: formData
        });
    });
```

Second modification is in `asyncRequest`:

```
....
method = options.type.toUpperCase();
if (options.data instanceof FormData) {
    options.processData = false;
    options.contentType = false;
    options.data.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data.append("X-HTTP-Method-Override", method);
    }
} else {
    options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });

    if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data.push({ name: "X-HTTP-Method-Override", value: method });
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This fix works, although I wish we could have away of implementing it without changing the the javascript library.

Comment: @DaveAgaba I agree with you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't refer `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, you don't get the `ajax` form, but a regular HTML form. And if you do, I suppose the form works fine, but it is not possible to upload a file with it, as ajax does not allow `multipart/form-data` enctype.

You can use HTML 5 File API ([Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)) or jQuery upload plugins.

Comment: Yes, I am opening partial view in jquery dialog box. post results are coming full postback. I need async to capture the results in dialog box.

Comment: @James123, so you need to use some jQuery upload plugins or implement your own.